# Apply SQL Server schema after 'schema compare' show error

Tags: sql-server-2016, azure-data-studio, schema-compare

Versions in use:

- SQL Server 2016
- Azure Data Studio 1.36.2
- SQL Server Schema Compare 1.13.1

Problem: there is something wrong with my Azure Data Studio apply schema to SQL Server 2016.

It say I'm not the login manager but there is no login manager role in SQL Server.

And it has worked before updating Azure Data Studio to v1.36.X

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqLa1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem
Misused sqllinlinetablevaluedfunction and sqlmultistatementtablevaluedfunction
In my project There are many function use sqllinlinetablevaluedfunction instead of sqlmultistatementtablevaluedfunction but It's should be used sqlmultistatementtablevaluedfunction
so I change to Correct Type then It's worked. The error never show